# Signal association after port mapping-VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am working in a TOP file of a project in VHDL. I have a problem-question concerning the port mapping.
Below, is a part of the code that I am trying to implement and afterwards the description of the context.

```
generate_microfib:
for i in 0 to 5 generate
        fib: microfib
           Port Map ( 
           InL => SignalNumber(num(i)*2 + i), --Input Left
           OutR => SignalNumber(num(i)*2 + i+1) --Output Right
           );
end generate generate_microfib;
```

The code above creates multiple components of microfib. The microfib, has an input and an output port. What I want to do is connect the left input of the current created component with the right output of the previous created one.
My initial thought was to do it inside the port mapping, but VHDL doesn't give many options for calculations in the for..generate statement. So, I decided to do it in two steps. Meaning that, I first create the desired components and afterwards do the connections (by setting the desired signals equal).

So, my question is: Is it possible to do the connections in a function for example, by setting:
SignalNumber(i)=SignalNumber(i-1)?
I know that the '<=' operator is accepted and not the '=' but I want to show you that my goal is to make those two signals equal and not assign the value of the one to the other.

Comment: You question is not clear. I suggest editing your post to make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is very straightforward to connect components via a for loop. I dont see what the problem is with your code example.

Answer (score 1):

When I've done things like this, I've used an array-type signal to act as an intermediate placeholder. Then, within the generate loop, you can connect the ports to the indexed locations on the array signal.

So you could try something like this, using `std_ulogic` as an example port type:

```
architecture rtl of entity is:
    constant N_DEVICES : integer := 5;
    signal port_connector : std_ulogic vector(N_DEVICES downto 0);
begin

    -- Concurrent statements

    generate_microfib : for i in N_DEVICES-1 downto 0 generate
        fib : microfib
            port map (
                InL => port_connector(i+1)
                OutR => port_connector(i)
            )
    end generate generate_microfib;
    
    -- Other stuff

end architecture rtl;
```

Then, `port_connector(N_DEVICES)` acts as the input to the chain, and `port_connector(0)` acts as the output from the chain.

This isn't a function, but it is (relatively) clean and avoids too much of a headache with the `generate` statement. Functions in VHDL, though, are meant to produce calculated values, not circuit connections, so I would recommend against trying for that anyhow.